# cProfile command line how to reduce output

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, cprofile

I'm trying to run cProfile on my python script and all I care about is the total time it took to run.  Is there a way to modify

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

so the output is just the total time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers supposes that you are using a Unix terminal. 
The fastest thing I can think of would be to redirect the results into a file with the  ">" operator and then read the file with head, something like:

```
python -m cProfile your_python_file.py > temp_file && head -n 3 temp_file
```

So basically,  to explain my self further, you are writing all the results of the profiling into temp_file (this file will get created if it doesn't exist and its name does not really matter ). And after this you display the first 3 lines of this file with `head -n 3` . Of course you will have to manually delete temp_file if you do not need it! Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I not somehow add the -n 3 to the initial command itself?  Sorry if that's a stupid question I'm just trying to speed up my job of recording times at various settings and opening a temp file wouldn't help

Comment: you could try to do  head -n 3 | python -m cProfile your_file.py , but I think you ll get an IOError, or at least that's what I get

Comment: well you can also add && rm temp_file to automatically clean the file :D and do all you want in one line.