# Filtering out irrelevant cProfile output

Tags: python, cprofile

I'm profiling a Python application with `cProfile`, and I find its output to be quite verbose. I am using this code to create the profile and visualize it:

```sh
PYTHONPATH=. \
    python3 \
    -m cProfile \
        -s cumtime \
        -o output.cprof \
    foo/__main__.py && \
gprof2dot \
    -f pstats \
    output.cprof | \
dot -Tpdf -o output.pdf
```

For example, here's part of a graph that I've created with [`gprof2dot`](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot):

[image]

Obviously, these are methods I am not interested in. I know, however, the name of the function I want to inspect, let's call it `foo:xxx:my_function`. How can I get the cProfile output filtered so that I can only look at this function and its callees?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058016/cprofile-command-line-how-to-reduce-output), but it only talks about looking at the `head` of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, `gprof2dot` has an option to filter function names.

So, I can just use `-z` with the name of the function on the node to see the descendants only:

```sh
python3 \
    -m cProfile \
        -s cumtime \
        -o output.cprof \
    foo/__main__.py && \
gprof2dot \
    -f pstats \
    -z "foo:xxx:my_function" \
    output.cprof | \
dot -Tpdf -o output.pdf
```